# My ajaxForm redirects to a PHP script

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

When I submit my form ajax always redirects to some.php, how can I prevent this from redirecting to the PHP script instead after submitting the form I want the page redirects to the index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Adapter &mdash; CKEditor Sample</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="../adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.js"></script>

<script>
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( '#editor1' ).ckeditor(); // Use CKEDITOR.replace() if element is <textarea>.
        $( '#editable' ).ckeditor(); // Use CKEDITOR.inline().
    } );

    function setValue() {
        $( '#editor1' ).val( $( 'input#val' ).val() );
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="f1" action="some.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="articletitle" id="articletitle" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Featured Image:</td>
        <td><input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152" type="hidden">
        <input name="image" id="image" type="file" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="save" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save").click(function(){
        $("#f1").ajaxForm();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me guys on this one.

Comment: This is because a submit buttons default behavior is to submit a form. You can prevent this by using `preventDefault()` in your click handler. [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#f1").ajaxForm();
    });
});
```

It should prevent your input from doing its default behavior of redirecting the page.

Edit:

To redirect to another page you should use something like:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

on the ajax's Success event.

Edit 2:

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4hF6e/3/ Make sure your references are correct. Seems to me the AjaxForm plugin has some way to prevent default behavior on the button.

Comment: You mean it still redirects?

Comment: @FioderickVillapañe what does your function ajaxForm() do?

Comment: @Jeemusu
It doesn't insert the data inside the database

Comment: @rakeshjain
It insert the data inside the database, as you can see I also have an image to be uploaded to my database.

Comment: Does it still redirect? If not, this is the answer. You appear to have a completely different problem relating to your AJAX. I would suggest looking at your XHR requests/responses in the network tab of Firebug/Chromes developer tools to see what errors you are getting. If you have more problems, start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of an `<input type="submit">` is to submit the form.

There two ways to fix this. The first one is to simply make your `input` a `button`. That will prevent the browser to send the form.

A better way though is to be JavaScript-independent and use what @Jeemusu said, use `preventDefault()` to prevent the submit to occur.

Comment: when I change the input to button the data in the form doesn't insert in my database.

Comment: @FioderickVillapañe that's a different question. Your question here applies to the redirect, not the database handling.

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
$("#save").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#f1").ajaxForm();

});
```

OR

```
$("#save").click(function(){
        $("#f1").ajaxForm();
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Use the first one. Always use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `type="submit"` you can use:

`type="button"`

or you can make use of `.preventDefault();`:

```
$("#save").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#f1").ajaxForm();

});
```

Comment: Don't say, `it doesn't work`. This is such a meaningless comment. Explain how it doesn't work. You asked how to stop your form redirecting to another page. This will almost certainly stop that from happening. If you want to ask a question about your AJAX failing, please start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could attach to the event "onsubmit" of the form. And return false in that function. i.e.:

```
$('#f1').submit(function() {
  // do your ajax stuff... and when completed (success) redirect 
  // using document.location.href = 'index.html';
  return false;
});
```